# SSMTP: Specifying default "full name" argument

Tags: linux, email-server

I have setup SSMTP on a few servers to all use the same email address to send mail from. Now, obviously, whenever I get a mail from one of these servers, the mails all originate from this same email address. I would like for the servers so send with a different "full name", e.g.:

- mail from ServerA: "Server A" <myservers@myhost.com>
- mail from ServerB: "Server B" <myservers@myhost.com>

Reading through the [SSMTP manfile](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ssmtp), I found the `-F` option, which should do exactly what I want. However, I can't find a way to set some default value for `-F`. My Google-fu is failing me. Is there any way to achieve what I want?

**[Edit]** Hm, so far, I hadn't bothered trying the `-F` command line flag. I just did and even that is not working for me. I have SSMTP setup to send with a GMail account. Could that be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SSMTP but most mail agents take their default full name values from the name field in `/etc/passwd`. You might try changing it for the originating user using `passwd -f` or manually editing the file to enter names. This is typically the 5th field in the file.

Comment: Thanks! I guess you mean ``chfn -f``? As far as I can see ``passwd`` doesn't accept an ``-f`` option. Doesn't seem to work for SSMTP though.

Comment: Ya, sorry that is a distro difference and I keep forgetting not all `passwd`s are created equal and my `passwd` command has *super ninja powers*.

Comment: What name **does** `SSMTP` pick up as the default? Maybe you could search for that name somewhere and figure out where it's coming from that way.

Comment: It's not picking up any name, mails are send from &lt;myservers@myhost.com&gt;, no full name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be able to setup aliases in the /etc/revaliases file.